# Where are the Life shops located?

Tags: fantasy-life

In Fantasy Life, there is a Life shop for each different life. Once you hit Master rank, they sell an incredible good item for that specific life (for example, I went up 30 in mining). However, I don't know all locations for the different lives, where are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The location for each life is in the below list. Please keep in mind that some locations may are not yet unlocked. Keep on enjoying the story line, to unlock it.

- **Paladin**: Mt. Snowpeak Summit
- **Mercenary**: Al Maajik Spelltown
- **Hunter**:: West Grassy Plains, Travellers Respite (close to entrace of Al Maajik)
- **Magician**: Al Maajik Spelltown, Esmeralda's Academy of Magic
- **Miner**: Mt. Snowpeak, well next to the house
- **Woodcutter**: Elderwood Village
- **Angler**: Port Puerto Palace Way, Angler's Association
- **Cook**: Castele Shopping District, Alfredo's Bistro
- **Blacksmith**: Mt. Snowpeak, Lava cave
- **Carpenter**: Elderwood Village
- **Tailor**: Port Puerto Palace Way, Madam Purl's House (the parrot)
- **Alchemist**: Al Maajik Sandtown, Prof. Snooze's Laboratory